# Programmatically deselect text

Tags: flutter

I have googled this using various synonyms like "deselect", "remove selection", "unselect", and tried calling `FocusNode().requestFocus()`, but other than manual user taps there is nothing that removes the selection on a text. Is this not possible?

My workaround is triggering a rebuild of the widget containing the `SelectableText`.

Comment: Provide more context as your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact way to programmatically deselect a text in a `SelectableText` widget. However, you could try doing a key reassignment. Follow the below:
Create a `key` for your selectable text widget

```
Key textKey = UniqueKey();
```

Create a deselect method that changes the value of the key.

```
void _deselectText() {
    setState(() {
      textKey = UniqueKey();
    });
  }
```

- Assign a Key to your SelectableText widget

```
SelectableText(
            'Some text that can be selected which we also want to reset.',
            key: textKey,
          ),
```

- Change the key by calling `_deselectText()` whenever you want to clear the selection. This should reset the widget.

Comment: The question already states that a workaround is rebuilding, which is what your suggestion achieves. btw, there is `UniqueKey` which doesn't require an extra method call to `now()`.

Comment: Yes, a UniqueKey is better. I'm aware of the rebuild, which is why i dropped a comment to provide more context. It all boils down to how the parent widget is composed.

However, as i stated; There is no exact way to programmatically deselect a text in a SelectableText widget.